# Reading SLG1 logs in a customer program

Tags: logging, abap

I'm developing a Gateway and Proxy interface for mutating SAP equipment data. In order to have an idea what's going on with the data that comes in, I've been logging the data using the `BAL_*` function modules. It works fine, it's been helpful so far.

Eventually though we are going to have end-users that work exclusively via the web front-end and will not have access to the SAP GUI. They cannot use transaction `SLG1`. As such, I've been asked to create a Gateway entity so that our front-end developers can make a beautiful view for the messages from the log. I've already noticed a handle is created for each log, for example something that looks like `051MjXRE7jMmdAR2X6GWoW`. I've made an association between each 'run' and each 'handle'.

I have googled plenty and come by the function group `BAL_DSP_LOG_DISPLAY`, as well as other `BAL_*` functions such as `BAL_LOG_EXIST` and so forth. No matter which of these functions I use, all of them continue to report that the log does not exist (and then in parenthesis, not found in memory). I also haven't really found an example of using these functions outside of first creating it and then immediately showing it afterwards. I'm assuming because the log was just created, the data is already in memory and can just be shown.

However, I can't do this. Most of the calls made to this interface are asynchronous and I cannot sent a message back to the client and there is no SAP GUI. As well, while digging around in the functions and coming back a macro that checks the memory, I've discovered that it apparently does, well nothing.

[image: Macro function inside the BAL function group]

[image: The load function which does nothing]

Does anybody with experience working with this log know how to properly prepare the function group for usage? I'm assuming I have to load this into memory before calling it, but I haven't been able to find one myself that would do something as such.

Comment: Why don't you read logs from database?

Comment: I don't know myself which tables are used, and the customer I'm working for prefers that we stick with the API provided by SAP instead of rolling out or own.

Comment: Following customer's desires is often a wrong approach. In this particular case it would be much faster and simpler to fetch necessary data from database.

Comment: @BryanAbrams Finally, a sensible customer...

Comment: @Suncatcher if I was in a position where I could have influenced this when the decision was made than I would have picked literally anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've made an association between each 'run' and each 'handle'.

That should not be necessary since you can store your "run ID" as external key (`BAL_S_LOG-EXTNUMBER`) in the protocol header data - but never mind.

You are right in assuming that the protocol needs to be loaded into memory first - that's what `BAL_DB_SEARCH` and `BAL_DB_LOAD` are for. There are plenty of demo programs and documentation available in the package `SZAL`. You may want to check `SBAL_DEMO_05` for this case.

---

Technical explanation of the technique above: The `FORM load` is used to ensure that the load (byte code) of the function group `SBAL` is loaded, since otherwise the `ASSIGN` statement would fail if that wasn't the case. It's just a safeguard against incorrect invocation, not an on-demand loading facility.

Comment: I'll check out the demo. I had bee looking for something but most people stop short of this in the documents I came across. A lot of attention goes to saving the log but not per se retrieving it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could read logs directly from DB joining `BALHDR` and `BALDAT` tables. `BALHDR` table contains `LOG_HANDLE` field which you can easily query using your collected handles.
 However, the most convenient way to do this is using `APPL_LOG_READ_DB` FM. This module contains plenty of search parameters which allow to retrieve any log you want.